# Como pegar somente a segunda classe com Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="Form1a1" class="abobrinha Form1comentarioA" />
</td>
```

tenho 2 classes dentro no meu input radio, no jQuery gostaria de selecionar apenas a última classe (que no meu caso é a segunda)

Comment: Não compreendi bem o que queres... Queres saber qual é a 2a classe desse elemento? podes explicar mais sobre o que estás a fazer e precisa dessa funcionalidade?

Comment: Como assim? Você não seleciona classes com jQuery, seleciona elementos (no caso o input).

Comment: @chocolatemontana alguma das respostas resolveu sua questão? Caso sim é importante marcar a resposta correta.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(":radio[name='Form1a1']").attr('class').split(' ')[1]
```

Explicação:

- `$(":radio[name='Form1a1']")` - obtém a lista de todos os Radiobuttons que possuem o atributo `name` igual a *Form1a1*;
- `.attr('class')` - obtém o valor do atributo 'class';
- `.split(' ')` - transforma a string em um array de strings, utilizando o espaço em branco como divisor;
- `[1]` - obtém o segundo membro da coleção.

Fonte:

[SO original, '*How to get the second class name from element?*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239947/how-to-get-the-second-class-name-from-element)

Comment: +1 por teres sido mais rápido :P

Answer (score 8):

## Apanhar a segunda classe

A mais rápido que me ocorreu é fazer uso do método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
$('input[name="Form1a1"]').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function() {
  alert($('input[name="Form1a1"]').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="5" name="Form1a1" class="abobrinha Form1comentarioA" />
```

No exemplo estamos:

1. Apanhar o conteúdo do atributo `class`;
2. Posteriormente a manipular a *string* partindo a mesma pelo espaço em branco ;
3. Finalmente ficamos apenas com a entrada `1` da matriz resultante do passo 2.

## Apanhar a última classe

Se a ideia for apanhar a última classe, ao invés de ficarmos com a entrada `1` da matriz resultante, podemos pular para o fim da mesma recorrendo ao método [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```
$('input[name="Form1a1"]').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function() {
  alert($('input[name="Form1a1"]').attr('class').split(' ').pop());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="5" name="Form1a1" class="abobrinha algumaCoisaMais Form1comentarioA" />
```

Comment: +1 por também ser uma resposta correta ;)

Answer (score 7):

As outras respostas referem bem como fazer isso com jQuery. Na verdade não é preciso jQuery para isso. Pode ser feito com JavaScript nativo assim:

```
var segundaClasse = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').classList[1];
```

O [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) é uma array com as classes todas do elemento. Selecionando a posição 1 dá a segunda classe (porque as arrays começam o index em zero).

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3k6t6uvz/

Comment: Cá temos o nosso VanillaJS a bombar :)

Comment: Muito boa essa do VJS.